# Changing Ion3's command key to Mod3+

Tags: emacs, metadata, ion3, windows-key

**How can you change successfully Ion3's command key to Mod3+ that is the Windows key at the left-hand-side?**

I put `META="Mod3+"` at the beginning of my /etc/X11/Ion/cfg_ion.lua, but Meta remains to be my command key. I use Emacs which is the reason I want to change the location of the command key.

The following is my current unsuccessful solution.

The script which I run:

**#filename: start.sh which I put to gnome-session-properties**

```
#!/bin/sh

/bin/sh /usr/local/sbin/session.bash
```

The .xmodmap -code

```
#filename: session.bash
! make left-window key another meta
remove Super_L
keycode 133 = Control_R

remove Lock = Caps_Lock
keycode 66 = Control_R
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `xmodmap` is what you need. It has explicit support for Meta keys, it's cross-platform and "window" manager independent.

Consider also mapping CTRL to CAPS LOCK, I'm sure you'll appreciate it.